In R create a new column from a column using the function case_when() with multiple conditional rules
I am trying to add a column. I have a column “Y” with values (numeric) going from -50 to 350, I would like to create a new column “Z” evaluating the values creating variables with the conditions from -30 to 30 = “Transition”, 31 to 100 = “Early”, 101 to 200 = “Mid”, 201 to 300 = “Late” everything else “NA” I am trying using the case_when function, within mutate function from dplyr, see code below. But keep getting erorr message. Any help will be very much appreciated
DataSetNew <- DataSet %>%
dplyr::mutate(ColumnZ = case_when(
ColumnY == < = 30 ~ "Transition",
ColumnY == between(31,100) ~ "Early",
ColumnY == between(101,200) ~ "Mid",
ColumnY == between(201,305) ~ "Late",
TRUE ~ "NA"
))
Error: unexpected '<' in:
"  dplyr::mutate(ColumnZ = case_when(
ColumnY == <"


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

You need to declare the column of interest inside the between() function. In your question you state 201-300 == "Late", but in your code the upper threshold for "late" is 305. This example uses the former.
Also, instead of TRUE ~ for all other values, the most recent advice is to use .default = instead.
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
DataSet <- data.frame(id = 1:9,
                      ColumnY = c(-30, 30, 31, 100, 101, 200, 201, 300, 301))

# Return ColumnZ
DataSetNew <- DataSet |>
  mutate(ColumnZ = case_when(between(ColumnY, -Inf, 30) ~ "Transition",
                             between(ColumnY, 31, 100) ~ "Early",
                             between(ColumnY, 101, 200) ~ "Mid",
                             between(ColumnY, 201, 300)  ~ "Late",
                             .default = NA))

DataSetNew
#   id ColumnY    ColumnZ
# 1  1     -30 Transition
# 2  2      30 Transition
# 3  3      31      Early
# 4  4     100      Early
# 5  5     101        Mid
# 6  6     200        Mid
# 7  7     201       Late
# 8  8     300       Late
# 9  9     301       <NA>

This is the equivalent of:
DataSetNew <- DataSet |>
  mutate(ColumnZ = case_when(ColumnY <= 30 ~ "Transition",
                             ColumnY >= 31 & ColumnY <= 100 ~ "Early",
                             ColumnY >= 101 & ColumnY <= 200 ~ "Mid",
                             ColumnY >= 201 & ColumnY <= 300  ~ "Late",
                             .default = NA))


@L Tyrone, Thank you so very much for your time and valuable knowledge. Your answer is incredible helpful, well structured  and provides clear explanation. I really appreciate it! Thank you very much to you and this forum for providing help Kind regards Virgilio

@L Tyron, many thanks for this and apologies it took me a while to do so. I have done as suggested upvoting and accepting great answers. Many thanks

it seems there are too many operators behind each other.
Check out the dplyr cheat sheet (google -> pdf) to get some idea how to use them.
You could try:
library (dplyr)
DataSetNew <- DataSet %>%
 mutate(ColumnZ = case_when(
  ColumnY < 30 ~ "Transition",
  ColumnY > 31 & ColumnY < 100 ~ "Early",
  ColumnY > 101 & ColumnY < 200 == between(101,200) ~ "Mid",
  ColumnY > 201 & ColumnY < 305 == between(201,305) ~ "Late")
)


thank you very much for your help this changest helped. I have now a reproducible code, and will have a look at the dplyr cheat sheet to keep improving. Many thanks for your time and input. Kind regars
